# Cast DataGridViewTextBoxCell to DatagridVIewButtonCell WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to cast   DataGridViewTextBoxCell to DatagridVIewButtonCell  on the specifics rows. I tried to do this by using the following code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewImport.Rows)
{
      if(row.Cells["Active"].Value.Equals("false"))
      {
            DataGridViewButtonCell buttonCell = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
            row.Cells["check"] = buttonCell;
      }
}
```

But it didn't work. Somebody knows what could be the problem? This behaviour had started after I bound the dataSource.

Also i had tried to create new column and its works,but i need buttons only for specific rows,not for all column

```
 DataGridViewButtonColumn btnColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            btnColumn.Name = "test";
            dataGridViewImport.Columns.Add(btnColumn);
```

All databindcode:

```
 public void prepareDataGridView()
        {
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            addColumnsToDataTable(dataTable);
            fillDataTable();
            dataGridViewImport.DataSource = dataTable;
            addHeaderCheckBox();
            addButtonsToUnactiveRows();
            styleDataGrid();      
        }


public void addColumnsToDataTable(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add("check");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Position");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Positionsindex");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Textindex");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Stichwort");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Menge");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("EH");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Active");
        }

      private void fillDataTable()
    {
        //FILL DATA
    }   


public void addButtonsToUnactiveRows()
   {
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewImport.Rows)
        {
              if(row.Cells["Active"].Value.Equals("false"))
              {
                    DataGridViewButtonCell buttonCell = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
                    row.Cells["check"] = buttonCell;
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is you try to index a cell using a string... you can't do row.Cells["Active"]. You need a number. I suppose the name of your column is Active?

Comment: I can index cell using rowName

Comment: So what is the error you get?

Comment: No errors. in code it had changed type of the Cell.But on datagrid there is no any changes.

Comment: Try using the Update() and Refresh(), this will redraw the user interface and tell me if there are any changes.

Comment: Nope,nothing changes=(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84438/discussion-between-anton-kozlovsky-and-gnqz).

Comment: Seem strange, can you post your `DataSource`'s binding code ?

Comment: I tested your code with a little modified and it work. I posted on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in event handling,because first of all,i bound data,then draw DataGrid and then try to add buttons.But i need to add buttons before drawing.So i find the solution with this event

```
private void dataGridViewImport_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            addButtonsToUnactiveRows();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code with somechange (didn't know if you mis-typed some name or intended) as follow, it work.

```
    DataTable dataTable;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        prepareDataGridView();
    }

    public void prepareDataGridView()
    {
        dataTable = new DataTable();
        addColumnsToDataTable(dataTable);
        fillDataTable();
        avaEditDataGridViewImport.DataSource = dataTable;
        //addHeaderCheckBox();
        addButtonsToUnactiveRows();
        //styleDataGrid();
    }


    public void addColumnsToDataTable(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add("check");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Position");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Positionsindex");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Textindex");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Stichwort");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Menge");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("EH");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Active");
    }

    private void fillDataTable()
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(j.ToString(), j, j, j, j, j, j, (j % 2 == 0 ? true : false));
        }
    }

    public void addButtonsToUnactiveRows()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in avaEditDataGridViewImport.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells["Active"].Value.ToString().Equals("False"))
            {
                DataGridViewButtonCell buttonCell = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
                row.Cells["check"] = buttonCell;
            }
        }
    }
```

There are some differences between yours code and mine (which work):

- I don't use addHeaderCheckBox() and styleDataGrid() (you did not show it here).
- fillDataTable()'s inside code.
- The `DataGridView` in addButtonsToUnactiveRows() and the `if` statement.

Hope you can solve soon :)

Comment: the problem is not in if.Problem in this code
                    DataGridViewButtonCell buttonCell = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
                    row.Cells["check"] = buttonCell;

Comment: Did you tried ? I tested your code, it work when `DataGridView`'s columns manually generated, but did not work when binding `DataSource`

Comment: yes, i put breakpoint into expression and its working.I will try create new column,instead of casting

Comment: It's a good workaround. Didn't know why your `if` line don't work with some data I generated but your code of creating new `DataGridViewButtonCell` work for me :)

Comment: Thanks for answer,but i already find my mistake.I need to put my code into DataBindingComplete and it owrks now=)